# On sort return entire DIV

Tags: javascript

**GOAL On sort return entire contents of div class="box"**

I have  x 4, each DIV has a variable "object".
The variable "object" works fine, the script finds the object adds 10 and then sorts correctly. In this example the script returns 20, 13, 11, 10 sorted greater to lower correctly. I need to return the contents of the entire **div class="box"**, not just the object item.
...
20 b b b b,
13 c c c c,
11 a a a a,
10 d d d d,

```
<!--CSS ===-->
    <style type="text/css">
.box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
}
</style>

    <!--HTML ===-->

<div id="containerSort">
  <div class="box">
    <object>
      001
    </object>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <object>
      10
    </object>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <object>
      03
    </object>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <object>
      0
    </object>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="increase"></div>
</div>

<!--JS ===--> 

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#increase").trigger("click");
    });

    // Assign function as eventListener
    $("#increase").click(computeAndUpdateValue);

    // Wrapper function
    function computeAndUpdateValue() {
    var valArr = getValues();
    valArr = addNumber(valArr);
    valArr = sortValues(valArr);
    createAndRenderHTML(valArr, "#containerSort");
    }

    function getValues(){
    var returnArray = [];
    $("div.box").each(function(id, el) {
    returnArray.push(parseInt($(el).text(), 10));
    });
    return returnArray;
    }

    function addNumber(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10) + 10;
    });
    }

    function sortValues(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0
    });
    }

    function createAndRenderHTML(arr, el) {
    var _html = arr.map(function(item) {
    return "<div class='box'> <object>" + item + "</object></div>"
    }).join("");
    $(el).html(_html);
    }
    //]]> 

    </script>
```

Comment: create array of object instead of just value, see my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be actually simplify, but as of now below solution will solve your problem

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#increase").trigger("click");
});

// Assign function as eventListener
$("#increase").click(computeAndUpdateValue);

// Wrapper function
function computeAndUpdateValue() {
    var valArr = getValues();
    valArr = addNumber(valArr);
    valArr = sortValues(valArr);
    createAndRenderHTML(valArr, "#containerSort");
}

function getValues() {
    var returnArray = [];
    $("div.box").each(function(id, el) {
        returnArray.push($(el));
    });
    return returnArray;
}

function addNumber(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        var $object = $(item).find("object");
        $object.text(parseInt($object.text(), 10) + 10);
        return item;
    });
}

function sortValues(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = parseInt($(a).find("object").text(), 10);
        b = parseInt($(b).find("object").text(), 10);
        return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
    });
}

function createAndRenderHTML(arr, el) {
    var _html = arr.map(function(item) {
        return "<div class='box'> <object>" + item.text() + "</object></div>"
    });
    $(el).empty().append(_html);
}
```

What I am doing here is

- creating the array of object
- sorting that object on the basis of value in object tag
- appending sorted array in container

I have created a js fiddle at : https://jsfiddle.net/7pjL17bu/

If you don't want to put whole div content then see the edited fiddle at : https://jsfiddle.net/7pjL17bu/1/

Comment: If this worked, please don't forgot to accept this as correct answer :)

Comment: Ive just realised I dont need the Object after SORT just

Comment: it appears you have removed the table and are only returning the data in this solution. I need the entire div returned including the table. Sorry missed that

Comment: And you want to remove object tag?

Comment: Now you can update the fiddle and get you desired result, if you have problem in understanding the script then please let me know, I will try to solve your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to extend `valArr` array to object since you want to store more that one data field,
so now in `valArr` there is `int` key which stands for value in `<object>` tag and `content` key is a string with `<td>` tags contents.
I've also changed all there functions so they'll be working with object data type :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#increase").trigger("click");
});

// Assign function as eventListener
$("#increase").click(computeAndUpdateValue);

  // Wrapper function
function computeAndUpdateValue() {
    var valArr = getValues();
    valArr = addNumber(valArr);
  console.log(valArr);
    valArr = sortValues(valArr);
    createAndRenderHTML(valArr, "#containerSort");
}

function getValues() {
    var returnArray = [];
    $("div.box").each(function(id, el) {
        var content = "";
        $(el).find("td").each(function(id, el) {
          content += " "+$(el).text();
        });
        returnArray.push({int:parseInt($(el).text(), 10),content: content});
    });
    return returnArray;
}

function addNumber(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        return {int:parseInt(item.int, 10) + 10, content: itemcontent};
    });
}

function sortValues(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {

        return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
    });
}

function createAndRenderHTML(arr, el) {
    var _html = arr.map(function(item) {
        return "<div class='box'> <object>" + item.int +" "+item.content+"</object></div>";
    }).join("");
    $(el).html(_html);
}
```

You can check out my implementation here: https://jsfiddle.net/eko24ive/npt3wa95/

Comment: hmm, you should see the same output as in @Ranjit Singh fiddle

Comment: Sorry tested several times, doesn't sort any thing. A good solution if I can show just the table data

Comment: here is screenshot of what I see using Chrome: [http://i.imgur.com/p3KPXEP.png](http://i.imgur.com/p3KPXEP.png)